# Localizing string properties of Attributes in c#

Tags: c#, localization, attributes, resx

Localizing properties of the class  are out of box by using the `DisplayAttribute`.

When trying to localize Attributes using a resource file `EmployeeResx.resx , EmployeeResx.fr.res....,` static class `EmployeeResx.Designer.cs` is generated with static string properties like:

```
public static string LastName {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("LastName", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

Trying to use the static string to localize the properties of the Attributes (Option in this example), like:

```
 [Option('l', "lastname",  HelpText = EmployeeResx.LastName)]
 public string  LastName { get; set; }
```

c# compiler raise error:

> Error CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

There are many attributes need to be localized.

How to localize the string properties of the Attributes like the above example?

Answer (score 2):

Make a derived attribute type. Pass the resource name into the derived attribute class. The derived attribute class can retrieve the resource string and pass it into the constructor of the base class.

If your Option attribute has a single string parameter, the derived class would be something like this.

```
internal class localized_OptionAttribute : OptionAttribute
{
  public localized_Option ( string ResourceName )
    : base ( <root namespace>.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString ( ResourceName ) )
  {
  }
}
```

Then you can use the new attribute in place of the original one:

```
[localized_Option("LastName")]
public string  LastName { get; set; }
```

where "LastName" is now used as the resource name.

It looks like your attribute has some additional parameters, which you would have to define as additional parameters to the constructor of the derived class. I have left them out for simplicity.